# Low alpha for NLTK agreement using MASI distance

Tags: annotations, nltk, distance, alpha

I'm getting a very low value for Krippendorff's alpha when I calculate agreement in NLTK using MASI as the distance function.

Three coders (Inky, Blinky, and Sue) are instructed to assign topic labels (love, gifts, slime, or gaming) to two texts (text01 and text02), based on what the texts are about. Each text can be about more than one topic, so coders may assign each text more than one label. The data and the code used to make the calculatons are shown below:

```
import nltk
from nltk.metrics import agreement
from nltk.metrics.distance import masi_distance
from nltk.metrics.distance import jaccard_distance

#(coder, item, label)
data = [('inky','text01',frozenset(['love','gifts'])), 
      ('blinky','text01',frozenset(['love','gifts'])), 
      ('sue','text01',frozenset(['love','gifts'])), 
      ('inky','text02',frozenset(['slime','gaming'])), 
      ('blinky','text02',frozenset(['slime'])), 
      ('sue','text02',frozenset(['slime','gaming']))]

jaccard_task = nltk.AnnotationTask(distance=jaccard_distance)
masi_task = nltk.AnnotationTask(distance=masi_distance)
tasks = [jaccard_task, masi_task]
for task in tasks:
    task.load_array(data)
    print("Statistics for dataset using {}".format(task.distance))
    print("C: {}\nI: {}\nK: {}".format(task.C, task.I, task.K))
    print("Pi: {}".format(task.pi()))
    print("Kappa: {}".format(task.kappa()))
    print("Multi-Kappa: {}".format(task.multi_kappa()))
    print("Alpha: {}".format(task.alpha()))
    print()
```

When I run the code, I get the following results:

```
Statistics for dataset using <function jaccard_distance at 0x09D26DB0>
C: {'inky', 'sue', 'blinky'}
I: {'text01', 'text02'}
K: {frozenset({'slime'}), frozenset({'love', 'gifts'}), frozenset   ({'gaming', 'slime'})}
Pi: 0.7272727272727273
Kappa: 0.7777777777777777
Multi-Kappa: 0.7499999999999999
Alpha: 0.75

Statistics for dataset using <function masi_distance at 0x09D26DF8>
C: {'inky', 'sue', 'blinky'}
I: {'text01', 'text02'}
K: {frozenset({'slime'}), frozenset({'love', 'gifts'}), frozenset({'gaming', 'slime'})}
Pi: 0.8172727272727272
Kappa: 0.8511111111111113
Multi-Kappa: 0.8324999999999998
Alpha: -1.5
```

My question is, why is the alpha so low when using the MASI distance function compared to Jaccard?

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: I encountered the same problem, my score using Jaccard is significantly higher than MASI on 3-rater, multi-label sets. I found this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2049, which says that MASI is weighted Jaccard but not sure how it matters in the dataset

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the error and got the correct value of Krippendorff's alpha with MASI distance when running the provided code. I used Python 3.5.2, NumPy 1.18.2, NLTK 3.4.5. Thus, the most probable answer would be that one need to update NLTK.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I couldn't reproduce the error either. Here's my result and I amusing NLTK 3.7.

```
Statistics for dataset using <function jaccard_distance at 0x1619e5b80>
C: {'blinky', 'inky', 'sue'}
I: {'text02', 'text01'}
K: {frozenset({'gifts', 'love'}), frozenset({'slime'}), frozenset({'gaming', 'slime'})}
Pi: 0.7272727272727273
Kappa: 0.7777777777777777
Multi-Kappa: 0.7499999999999999
Alpha: 0.75

Statistics for dataset using <function masi_distance at 0x1619e5c10>
C: {'blinky', 'inky', 'sue'}
I: {'text02', 'text01'}
K: {frozenset({'gifts', 'love'}), frozenset({'slime'}), frozenset({'gaming', 'slime'})}
Pi: 0.6372727272727272
Kappa: 0.7044444444444444
Multi-Kappa: 0.6675
Alpha: 0.6781219748305904
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).